# How to test for the presence of child nodes in a React-Boilerplate component

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme, react-boilerplate

I'm working on my first react-boilerplate tests for a component and this has me reading documents from various overlapping sources and unsure which pieces apply.

Given the component:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const MegaLogoBase = styled.div`
  //Styling
`;

const C = styled.span`
  //Styling
`;

const T = C.extend`
  //Extended Styles
`;

function MegaLogo() {
  return (
    <MegaLogoBase>
      <C>C</C>
      <T>T</T>
    </MegaLogoBase>
  );
}

export default MegaLogo;
```

I feel like my test should be something along the lines of:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow,} from 'enzyme';

import MegaLogo from '../index';

describe('<MegaLogo />', () => {
  it('Renders a Div', () => {
    const RenderedComponent = shallow(<MegaLogo />);
    expect(RenderedComponent.find('div')).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

But instead of getting a nice node list of containing a `<div>` instead I get a very complex object which fails the test.

I'd debated opening this as an issue on the React-Boilerplate github but I suspect it's me  not grokking something rather than an issue.